# PHP products category select dropdown that allows user to define category as main category or child category

Tags: php, mysql, recursive-query

I have a form that contains select dropdown list of categories. When user adds a new category he is supposed to choose from all main categories with parent="0" or from their child categories.
My database structure is:

```
id || bg_category || parent  ==> and for example I have:    
1  || Jewellery   ||  0    
2  || Rings       ||  1    
3  || Ear rings   ||  2    
4  || Bracelets   ||  0
```

The condition is that a parent category can not be added as child category to its child category or to itself.
So far I have this function:

```
public function getMasterCategories($cid = 0) {
    echo '<option value="0" selected="true">No category</option>';
    if (empty($cc))
        $cc = 9999999999;
    $que = 'select id, bg_category,parent from products_categories group by id order by bg_category';
    $res = mysql_query($que) or die('Mysql Error:' . mysql_error() . '<br /> Query:' . $que);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
        $rw = mysql_fetch_row($res);
        if ($c == $rw[0])
            echo '<option value="', $rw[0], '" selected="true">', $rw[1], '</option>';
        else
            echo '<option value="', $rw[0], '">', $rw[1], '</option>';
    }
}
```

Now this function returns all categories and show availability to make a child category to be parent to its mother category.

WORKING FUNCTION:

```
function getMasterCategories($c=0,$cc=0){
echo '<option value="0" selected="true">Няма</option>';
if(empty($cc)) $cc=9999999999;
$que='select id, bg_category,parent from products_categories where id="'.$cc.'"';
$res=mysql_query($que) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$que);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($res);
$rw=mysql_fetch_row($res);

    if($rw[0]>0){
    $querys='select id,bg_category,parent from products_categories where parent="'.$cc.'" order by bg_category';
    $results=mysql_query($querys) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$querys);
    $num_rs=mysql_num_rows($results);
    if($num_rs=="0"){
    $query='select id,bg_category,parent from products_categories where id!="'.$cc.'" order by bg_category';
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$query);
    $num_r=mysql_num_rows($result);

    for($i=0;$i<$num_r;$i++){
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $q='select id,bg_category,parent from products_categories where parent="'.$cc.'" and id="'.$row[0].'" order by bg_category';
    $r=mysql_query($q) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$q);
    $ro=mysql_fetch_row($r);
    if(empty($ro[0])){
        if($c==$row[0]) echo '<option value="',$row[0],'" selected="true">',$row[1],'</option>';
        else echo '<option value="',$row[0],'">',$row[1],'</option>';
        }
    }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your php code is wrong. Double check your curly brackets

Comment: correct! Now is OK, jst copy paste error, sorry

Comment: Also,  `$c` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can add another enrty for adding parent category to its child category.

```
id || bg_category || parent  ==> and for example I have:    
1  || Jewellery   ||  0    
2  || Rings       ||  1    
3  || Ear rings   ||  2    
4  || Bracelets   ||  0
5  || Jewellery   ||  2
```

In above case, I tried to add `Jewellery` category under `Rings` category. However, new `Jewellery` category has different id

If you provide your insert statement, I can help on that query too

Comment: thank you for your help but I sucessed to manage the problem, here is the solution updated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Working function :

```
function getMasterCategories($c=0,$cc=0){
echo '<option value="0" selected="true">Няма</option>';
if(empty($cc)) $cc=9999999999;
$que='select id, bg_category,parent from products_categories where id="'.$cc.'"';
$res=mysql_query($que) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$que);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($res);
$rw=mysql_fetch_row($res);

    if($rw[0]>0){
    $querys='select id,bg_category,parent from products_categories where parent="'.$cc.'" order by bg_category';
    $results=mysql_query($querys) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$querys);
    $num_rs=mysql_num_rows($results);
    if($num_rs=="0"){
    $query='select id,bg_category,parent from products_categories where id!="'.$cc.'" order by bg_category';
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$query);
    $num_r=mysql_num_rows($result);

    for($i=0;$i<$num_r;$i++){
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $q='select id,bg_category,parent from products_categories where parent="'.$cc.'" and id="'.$row[0].'" order by bg_category';
    $r=mysql_query($q) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$q);
    $ro=mysql_fetch_row($r);
    if(empty($ro[0])){
        if($c==$row[0]) echo '<option value="',$row[0],'" selected="true">',$row[1],'</option>';
        else echo '<option value="',$row[0],'">',$row[1],'</option>';
        }
    }
    }

}
```

}